How to start CDC in flink sql connector of Apache IoTDB version 1.3.0?
Both the server and the client I am using now are Apache IoTDB version 1.3.0. I want to use the CDC function in Flink SQL IoTDB Connector, but after I completed all configuration settings, seems like it is still not started. I checked the official guide and nothing new popped out. I want to know does CDC need to be turned on manually, and how to turn it on?

Try executing flush in Cli tool of Apache IoTDB. Since the pipe event that CDC depends on is not sent in real time in the open-source version, so executing flush is needed to trigger it. If you need to send the pipe in real-time, you can consider to use the enterprise version.
